# Rust installation fails on Linux with error "OS 21"

Tags: linux, rust, installation

When I tried to install Rust on my Linux machine this error appeared:
`error: could not amend shell profile: '/home/$Username/.profile': could not write rcfile file: '/home/$Username/.profile': Is a directory (os error 21)`

Answer (score 0):

Many unix-like systems use the `~/.profile` **file** as a point to place startup code for a user session. There are also [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer) files with a similar function. You should not use that file for any other purpose (like for example it beeing a directory).

Your installation script apparently wants to add some content to that file. This is not unusual, because `~/.profile` can be used to set up the search path for programs.

You should rename (or delete) the `~/.profile` directory.

I had to delete my .profile folder.

Comment: (because `.profile` should be a file -- it's the shell-agnostic equivalent to `.bash_profile` and similar; if you want a directory, name it `.profile.d`)

Comment: Perhaps also ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/